# Having a lot of memory leaks working around pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to copy all the contents from a static 3D char array (`e`) into a dynamic one (`C`). After compiling and starting gdb I noted that the address contained within `*C[0]` changes to a wrong one.

```
 *C[0] = <0x601030>
 *C[0] = <0x60105000601030>
 *C[0] = <0x60105000601030>
 *C[0] = <0x60105000601030>
 *C[0] = <0x60105000601030>
 *C[0] = <0x60105000601030>
```

This is the program code:

```
int
main ()
{
  #define I 2
  #define J 3

  int *C[I];

  const char *e[I][J] = {{"aa", "bb", "cc"}, {"dd", "ee", "ff"}}; 

  for (int i=0; i<I; i++)
  {
    int *P = malloc(sizeof(int)*J); 
    C[i] = P;       
    for (int j=0; j<J; j++)  
    { 
      char *p;      
      p = malloc(strlen(e[i][j])+1);
      strcpy(p, e[i][j]);
      P[j] = p;                    
      char **ptx = C[0];               
      printf("*C[0] = <%p>\n", *ptx); 
    }
  }
}
```

What's supposed to be wrong within the given code above?

Comment: `*(P+j)`..we generally use `P[j]`, more readable, IMHO.

Comment: `const char *e[J][I]` --> `const char *e[I][J]`

Comment: `char **ptx = C[0];`....emmm what is that supposed to be?

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled would catch a lot of your problems: http://ideone.com/bzDiRK

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Doing that fixed the segfault and the missing "cc". But only one problem remains - C[0, 0] address is always getting wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh ptx is a pointer to the pointer pointing to each character of the strings.

Comment: Why are you using an Array of `int` type (`int C[I];`)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY in order to store the addresses of the pointers

Comment: I think use `char *C[I * J];` or `char **ptx = malloc(I * J * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: There is no 3D array in your code. Only a 2D array of pointers and other pointers.

Comment: With `C` being declared as an array of *int*, why are you setting elements with values of type (converted from) *`int *`*?

Comment: @JohnBollinger In order to assign the addresses of the values of type `int*` to each member of C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I wasn't aware of this before - that's what caused the problem. Using void** instead, is what is supposed to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your indexing mixed up with the `e` array. You define it thus:

```
const char *e[J][I] = {{"aa", "bb", "cc"}, {"dd", "ee", "ff"}};
```

Which is saying there are 3 lots of 2...but you've got 2 lots of 3. Later on you access it with the ordering of the indexes the other way around

```
p = malloc(strlen(e[i][j])+1);
```

which should work if your earlier assignment has the indexing corrected to be `e[I][J]`.

As for your problems with `C` it is because you're confusing `int` with pointers. They might not be the same size and this is why you're seeing your issue. You should instead being using `void *` to store values of pointers as I've done with a revised (and working) version of your code.

```
void **C[I];
const char *e[I][J] = {{"aa", "bb", "cc"}, {"dd", "ee", "ff"}};

for (int i=0; i<I; i++)
{
  void **P = malloc(sizeof(void **)*J);
  C[i] = P;       
  for (int j=0; j<J; j++)
  { 
    char *p;
    p = malloc(strlen(e[i][j])+1);
    strcpy(p, e[i][j]);
    P[j] = p;
    printf("*C[0] = <%p>\n", *C[0]);
  }
}
```

You should also remember to `free` the memory you've allocated when it's no longer required as it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake which caused the segfault and the missing "cc". But only one problem still remains - C[0, 0] address is always getting wrong.

Comment: That is because you don't have `C[0,0]` - C is defined as an `int` array - it doesn't have a second dimension. I've updated my answer with more information on how to sort that mess out too.

Comment: Yes I know .. you're right, but I mean by C[0], 0] the copy of e[0][0] which is contained within *ptx (ptx contains the address of C[0]).

Comment: "you've defined it incorrectly as an int array when you actually want an array of int *" - does this suggest that `int *C[I];` is what should be done?

Comment: Yup - that's what I said in my revised answer

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, yet `*C[0]` is still changing from its value 0x601030 to 0x60105000601030.

Comment: I've worked out what your problem is and have revised my answer again.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm - that's what I was looking for .. Finally, I understand my mistake :). Thanks a lot, bro.

Answer (score 2):

First, [as suggested by Bluepixy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323497/having-a-lot-of-memory-leaks-working-around-pointers?noredirect=1#comment73711229_43323497), `const char *e[J][I]` should be `const char *e[I][J]`.

Even after that, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Look here

```
  char **ptx = C[0];
```

you define `ptx` to be a `char **`, then you (*try to*) initialize it with an `int` (which itself is an implementation defined behaviour, integer to pointer conversion) and finally, you try to dereference that pointer.

There's absolutely no guarantee that you're dereferencing a valid memory, which in turn leads to UB.

***Moral of the story:*** Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.

Comment: the dereferencing of ptx is supposed to contain the address of e[0][0] since *ptx is *(ptx+0), and ptx is C[0].